# How to create this XML O/p in java using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

This is the output I should get from my java code. How to create an XML like this in Java. I have read some tutorials But still want to get an o/p like this. Just give  me a coding to build this. I will do other steps of myself.

```
    This should be generated from my java code using JAXB

             <place id="p1">

               <graphics>

               <position x="150.0" y="75.0"/>

               </graphics>

               <name>

               <value>p1</value>


               <graphics>

               <offset x="50.0" y="0.0"/>

               </graphics>

               </name>

               <initialMarking>

               <value>0</value>

               <graphics>

               <offset x="0.0" y="0.0"/>

               </graphics>

               </initialMarking>

               <capacity>

               <value>0</value>

               </capacity>

               </place>
```

Comment: What's an *o/p*?
Also, is this a homework? If so, tag the question appropriately.

Comment: What have you tried?  The following will help get you started:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can have a good insight on writing XML File from Java code in the following link -

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/477.html

Hope this help you. If you still have problem with your java code, post it - we will review those.